# "Waiting for" or "Awaiting for"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

When writing a letter, should I use

> "Waiting for your approval"

or

> "Kindly awaiting for your approval"

?

Comment: What dictionaries have you checked?  What did they say?  What part of what they said confuses you? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Who is being kind here? Are you really awaiting that kindly?

Answer (score 4):

The word 'wait' is used in the sense of 'remain'. On the other hand, the word 'await' is used in the sense of 'wait on' or 'expect'. This is the main difference between the two words.

[image: waiting for vs awaiting]

Comment: (1) We prefer that you don’t post images of text. Copy (or paraphrase) the information and link to the source. (2) It’s not clear to me how this actually *answers* the question. (3) Nor is it clear to me what “wait” has to do with “remain”.

Answer (score 2):

Although "waiting for" is acceptable, "awaiting for" is not because "await" means "wait for".  Writing "await for" would be redundant.

When sending letters by mail, you likely want to be as formal as possible. "Kindly awaiting your approval" would fit this purpose.